# Optaplanner, use of @ValueRangeProvider

Tags: optaplanner

I need some help on the use of @ValueRangeProvider inside a @PlanningEntity

I have used the nursingShift example principle, where the Plannningsolution is instantiated by a rest service call, it then gets all the data, fact, ect via Hibernate and creates a solution.

```
SolverJob<MySolution, Long> res = solverManager.solveAndListen(MySolutionRepository.SINGLETON_SOLUTION_TABLE_ID,
                mySolutionRepository::findById,
                mySolutionRepository::save
                );
```

This solution then gets all the facts, data, etc. and start the solver. But once inside a  class, I need to restrict the possible employees that can be assigned to a meeting by accessing the PlanningSolution, which has the list of Employees and filter it. I'm trying to solve it with [4.3.5.2.3.](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.7.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#valueRangeProviderOnPlanningEntity)  the  @ValueRangeProvider inside the @PlanningEntity depending on the type of employee, but not sure how to get a ref, back to the original list that has all the original employees? Also should there be the @ValueRangeProvider in both the planningentity and planningsolution or only the first.

```
        @PlanningSolution
        public class MySolution {
            ...
            @ValueRangeProvider
            @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
            private List<Employee> employeeList;
    
            @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
            private List<Meeting> MeetingList;
        ...

}

    @PlanningEntity
    public class Meeting{
        ...
        @PlanningVariable (nullable = true)
        private Employee employee;
        ...
         @ValueRangeProvider
        public List<Employee> getFilteredEmployeeList() {
            
            "Get the original list from MySolution by some reference or build in auto-detection in optaplaner and filter it, based on the employees type"
            
            return employeeList;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution will depend on the type of limitation you want to implement:

- If any employee can be assigned to any meeting just keep valueRangeProvider at PlanningSolution level
- If there is some meeting specific limitation start with implementing it as constraint
- Only if constraint does not work well for you, should you create PlanningEntity level value provider. The easiest way will be precalculate List of possible values at problem generation time and simply return it as valueRangeProvide. In this case you do not need ValueRangeProvider at PlanningSolution level

Comment: Right, i do need do differ - i think- as im using some dummy values to model that some meetings actually dont need an employee, but I cannot tell optaplanne that some meertings should not have employees and some should, then I made a 'singleton'  dummy-placeholder-employee that all those meeting should use, but rather than trying all possible employess before it find the dummy, then I  think performacewise ,its better that it gets a filteres employeelist with just that one option. So when loading the soution I will remove the current rangeprovider, then try to split into two.

Comment: I would try following approach:

1. Mark PlanningVariable nullable allowing not to assign employee to the meeting

2. Create constraint that will penalyze (using hard score) meetings without **required** employees

This is more straightforward approach.

Comment: Ok that does work, but I thought was an ineffective approach as it always seems to try more or less all possibilities before setteling on the dummy employee

Comment: Making only one value in range available some times lead optaplanner into never ending loop (with "bailing out of ..." warnings) when it tries to find "another, better values". In you case I would probably implement entity level filter so optaplanner would not try to change employees for the meetings that do not need one.

Comment: ok thx, i reverted to the split so the dummy employeetype, now gets a filtered list of only one possible option, while the normal employees get the normal list. this also works now.